# Java false sharing in multiple thread problem

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```java
class PersonValue {
    volatile public int valueA;
    @Contended
    volatile public int valueB;
}

class Person extends Thread {

    public final static long ITERATIONS = 500L * 1000L * 1000L ;
    public static volatile PersonValue personValue = new PersonValue();
    int index = 0;
    public Person(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long i = ITERATIONS;
        while (--i > 0) {
            if (index == 0) {
                personValue.valueA = 3;
            } else {
                personValue.valueB = 3;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TestContend {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Person person = new Person(0);
        Person person1 = new Person(1);


        person.start();
        person1.start();

        person.join();
        person1.join();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Duration " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(end - start));
    }
}
```

Output：

`Duration 3`

When I comment  the `@Contended` code in `PersonValue`,and output：
`Duration 11`

The above output meets my expectations, but I modified the code as follows:

```java
class Person extends Thread {

    public final static long ITERATIONS = 500L * 1000L * 1000L ;

    public volatile static int personValuesA = 3;
    public volatile static int personValuesB = 1;

    int index = 0;

    public Person(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long i = ITERATIONS;
        while (--i > 0) {
            if (index == 0) {
                personValuesA = 3;
            } else {
                personValuesB = 3;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TestContend {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Person person = new Person(0);
        Person person1 = new Person(1);


        person.start();
        person1.start();

        person.join();
        person1.join();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Duration" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(end - start));
    }
}
```

Output:

`Duration 12`

Then I added the annotation `@Contended` in `personValuesB`:

```java
class Person extends Thread {
    //...

    public volatile static int personValuesA = 3;
    @Contended
    public volatile static int personValuesB = 1;
}
```

And output:
`Duration 12`

The two programs run the same time. Why?

My problems:

1. Why is the running time the same after adding @Contended annotation？

Comment: What does `@Contended` do?  What framework is it from?

Comment: @markspace It is in the JDK and prevents false sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Contended` does not work on static fields, only on instance fields.

Comment: Why is it not working in static fields?Will static fields not be cached?

Comment: @范明毅 It is by design. What do you mean by 'cached'?